# Bash Scripting: Trying to find files using ls wild-carding

Tags: bash, loops, scripting

Here's my problem: I have to resolve various filenames/locations (data directory may have sub-directories) which are user-configurable. If I can resolve the filename completely prior to the loop the following script works:

```
[prompt] more test.sh
#! /usr/bin/env bash

newfile=actual-filename

for directory in `find -L ${FILE_PATH}/data -type d`; do
    for filename in `ls -1 ${directory}/${newfile} 2>/dev/null`; do
        if [[ -r ${filename} ]]; then
            echo "Found ${filename}"
        fi
    done
done

[prompt] ./test.sh
[prompt] Found ${SOME_PATH}/actual-filename
```

However, if newfile has any wildcarding in it the inner-loop will not run. Even if it only returns a single file.

I would use find with some regex, but to auto-generate the proper expressions and do the substitutions for somethings will be tricky (e.g. pgb.f0010{0930,1001}{00,06,12,18} would correlate to some files associate with Sep. 30 and Oct 1 of 2010 the first grouping is computed by my script for a provided date).

```
pgb.f0010093000 pgb.f0010093006 pgb.f0010093012 pgb.f0010093018 pgb.f0010100100
pgb.f0010100106 pgb.f0010100112 pgb.f0010100118
```

I'm running Fedora 15 64-bit.

Comment: Note that `for varname in $(ls -1 fileglob 2>/dev/null)` is just a slightly-buggier way to write `for varname in fileglob`. (In your case: `for filename in $directory/$newfile`.)

Comment: Someone once told me:  You should never try to parse or iterate over the output of ls: http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs

Comment: I tried not to, but there isn't a regextype argument for find that is compatible with something like pgb.f0010{0930,1001}{00,06,12,18} which works fine in ls.

Comment: Also checked: varname in fileglob does not actually get the files which match the pattern.

Comment: Please list an actual example of filenames that are being matched to clarify what is being asked.

Comment: I did both in the original post and my previous comments:

pgb.f0010{0930,1001}{00,06,12,18}

Which would correspond to:
pgb.f0010093000
pgb.f0010093006
pgb.f0010093012
pgb.f0010093018
pgb.f0010100100
pgb.f0010100106
pgb.f0010100112
pgb.f0010100118

I appreciate the help. I'm considering using a Java option at this point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The root problem is that there is a dependence on shell expansion in the broken script.  Use eval:

```
#! /usr/bin/env bash
FILE_PATH="."
newfile=pgb.f0010{0930,1001}{00,06,12,18}

for directory in `find -L ${FILE_PATH}/data -type d`; do
    for filename in `eval ls -1 ${directory}/${newfile} 2>/dev/null`; do
        if [[ -r ${filename} ]]; then
            echo "Found ${filename}"
        fi
    done
done
```

Comment: Thanks. Trying to auto-generate the regex for something like {0930, 1001} in the script was more work than I wanted to do.

Comment: Perhaps. The regex for the glob "{0930,1001}" seems no more difficult to compute than the glob itself. The regex is "(0930)|(1001)". The glob character "?" translates to ".", and "\*" translates to ".\*".

Answer (score 3):

```
newfile="*"
find -L ${FILE_PATH}/data -name "${newfile}" \
| while read filename
  do
    if [[ -r ${filename} ]]; then
      echo "Found ${filename}"
    fi
  done
```

-or-

```
newfile="*"
find -L ${FILE_PATH}/data -name "${newfile}" -readable -exec echo "Found {}" \;
```

-or with regular expressions-

```
newfile='.*/pgb.f0010(0930|1001)(00|06|12|18)'
FILE_PATH=.
find -L ${FILE_PATH}/. -regextype posix-extended \
  -regex "${newfile}" -readable -exec echo "Found {}" \;
```

Comment: Yes, find works for -name *, but find does not seem to be able to handle the example I gave above: -name pgb.f0010{0930,1001}{00,06,12,18}

Comment: Then replace -name with -regex ?

Comment: I would like to support the glob options so novice *nix users can test using the ls command.

Comment: Use of `ls -1 pgb.f0010{0930,1001}{00,06,12,18}` is novice? I have used *nix since before linux, and never used that notation before this question was asked. Not that I am a typical novice, but in this use perhaps, since I learned something from the question.

Comment: In the long term, teaching a novice regular expressions might prove more valuable than teaching them arcane file globbing skills.